# How to distinguish between no location update and no location fix in Android?

Tags: android, locationmanager

I have an Android app where I should somehow clearly distinguish between whether user has not moved for an amount of time or location was not resolved during that interval. As I understand in both cases I will not receive any update if I `requestLocationUpdates()`.
Does anybody has an idea on how to implement this?

The sample case is:

1. I've got 2 valid and accurate locations: 1 from GPS and 1 from network; Good, that's exactly what I need.
2. One minute has passed: the user may have gone to a kind of underground station and lost gps/network (and ability to resolve location) OR may have not moved at all;
3. Now I have to decide whether the location is perfectly relevant (user not moved) or I have no location at all (all providers lost). But how? Seems like in both cases I receive no location updates.

Comment: There's no way to detect that user has moved without getting the next update on location.

Comment: Seems like from GPS I receive updates very frequently even for minor moves and for network provider I have rather relevant status in contrast to GPS' one. Have to check whether I can rely on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`LocationClient.getLastLocation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html#getLastLocation%28%29). You can store this location and check against it later.

Comment: I collect locations continuously, but even then I can't guess whether last location is still valid.

Comment: Well, it's hard to give advice without knowing more about the use case. If it's any help, Location has a method `getElapsedRealtimeNanos()`

Comment: Thanks, I have access to Android API. I'll update the question with an example case.